# Multiple RewriteCond, How Would This Code Work?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I have this in my *.conf file ( I got this from someone else, not sure whether there is a bug or not), which I don't quite understand:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mycompany.com
  RewriteRule ^$  http://mycompany.com/login   [L]
  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
   RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I roughly understand what it does; first it checks whether the incoming request is `mycompany.com`, if yes, then redirects to `http://mycompany.com/login`.

Then, what is the next condition to check? The fact that there is this

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
```

come before the `RewriteRule ^$  http://mycompany.com/login   [L]` is confusing me.

Is there anyway to rewrite the above script in a `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule` format?

Answer (score 1):

You have a ambiguous indentation of your configuration file.

Maybe the following is a bit clearer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the requested hostname is mycompany
# and no path segment was given,
# redirect to /login
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mycompany.com
RewriteRule ^$  http://mycompany.com/login   [L]

# Add .html extension to any requested filename.
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]

# Check if requested filename (now with .html
# extension) exists,
# otherwise redirect to front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I removed

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
```

because this could more easily be done with the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

Comment: OK, does this mean that if it's not redirected to `/login`, then it will add .html extension to any request filename, and only then proceeds to the last `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what these RewriteRules do.